# Learning Flask, Can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flask, get

I recently started learning Flask. I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server database and display a table. I'm not sure if I'm doing the connection string correctly.

I'm not sure what the password is for the server. Been connecting with windows Authentication in SQL server management studio. Do I need this with the connection string for a local database?

I'm not sure what to do to get this working. I've been working on this for hours and I'm not really getting anywhere. pyodbc.connect connected in pyCharm but not in the browser. Whatever I try I get the error message "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

```
from flask import Flask, g, render_template, abort, request
import json
import pypyodbc as pyodbc

##cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
##                     "Server=LAPTOP-16DOMG6S\MSSQLSERVER3;"
  ##                    "Database=ImportTest;"
    ##                 "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

CONNECTION_STRING = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=LAPTOP->16DOMG6S\MSSQLSERVER3;' \
                   'Database=ImportTest;' \
                    'Uid = LAPTOP-16DOMG6S\dmc03' \
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

##Displays the database table in pycharm with pyodbc.connect
##for row in cursor:
 ##  print('row = %r' % (row,))


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    try:
        g.sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING, autocommit=True)
    except Exception:
        abort(500, "No database connection could be established.")

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    try:
        g.sql_conn.close()
    except AttributeError:
        pass





##Landing Page. Connection Working?

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return 'This will display article information '



##Display All Articles in Database

@app.route('/articles', methods=['GET'])
def allArticle():
    curs = g.sql_conn.cursor()
    query = 'select * from ImportTest.dbo.gwTable2 '
    curs.execute(query)

    columns = [column[0] for column in curs.description]
    data = []

    for row in curs.fetchall():
        data.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
   return json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the exact error you are getting from the python console? We are unable to help otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in comment above the `CONNECTION_STRING` variable, you have the server as being `LAPTOP-16DOMG6S\MSSQLSERVER3`, but in the variable there is an extra `>` in it:

```
# Original
LAPTOP-16DOMG6S\MSSQLSERVER3\

# Variable
LAPTOP->16DOMG6S\MSSQLSERVER3
       ^
       | Notice the right arrow
```